# Many-to-many relationship with three classes

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

In begining i have to say that i don't know if it must be many-to-many relationShip

Lets say i have three classess:

User-detalis, which have some basic user-information like region, city

```
public class UserDetails
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string City{get;set;}
  public strng Region{get;set;}
}
```

Next class is UserDetailsDictionary

```
public class UserDetailsDictionary
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string DetailsType{get;set;}
 }
```

This class will containts values like :

```
Name = "football", detailsType="interests",
Name = "basketball", detailsType="interests",
Name = "brown", detailsType="eyes",
Name = "green", detailsType="eyes"
```

and the last one class, should contains information about joining userDetails with Dictionary and Values:

```
 public class JoiningClass
   {
     public UserDetails UserDetails{get;set;}
     public UserDetailsDictionary DictionaryItem{get;set;}
     public bool Value{get;set;}
   }
```

And values in this class should be like :

```
(1,1,0)
(1,1,1)(first user like basketball)
(1,2,0)(first user does not have brown eyes)
(2,1,1) (second user likes football)
```

And in the code i would like to check value from two ways, i mean:

```
UserDetailsDictionary type;
...
var val1 = _dbContext.UserDetails.Where(x=> x.DictionaryItem.Id == type.Id).Value;
```

and from the other ways

```
UserDetails ud;
...
var allDetailsOfUser = _dbContext.UserDetailsDictionary.ToArray();
```

and also, let's say i want to find all users(userDetails) with brown eyes:

```
var dictionaryItem = _dbContext.UserDetailsDictionary.Where(x=>x.Name == "eyesColor").SingleOrDefault();

var userDetails = _dbContext.JoiningClass...?
```

How should i create these classess?
How to create correcrt relations to entity framework (core 2.0) in DbContext class?

Comment: You can have third class act as viewModel which will contain 3 properties - ID of UserDetails , ID of UserDetailsDictionary and Your bool value , By Storing ID's in this way (which will work as foreign key) you can fetch there respective details very easily

Comment: It is a web app (ASP.Net Core MVC) ?

Comment: it is Web API but its fully separated from the business-logic and DAL layers, so it is does not matter i think. Why shouyld some viewModel know about database architecture ?
my question is abaout how to define classess in database and how to properly map them to entity framework

Comment: sorry, i havent read properly your first comment. Yes if i have thrid class contains userDetailsId, dictionaryItemId, value it is very simple model and i can query it manually from linq, but i also want to query from other contexts, like from userDetails to DictionaryItem (like i have wrote in post)
and also i dont know how to map this to EF, because i have to say that UserDetailsId is FK, DictionaryItemID is FK, and both these values are PrimaryKey of table

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works for you

I will suggest you to normalized these table as

1.] First Model and Table Columns

```
public class UserDetails
{
  public int UserId{get;set;}
  public string UserName{get;set;}
  public string City{get;set;}
  public strng Region{get;set;}
}
```

2.] Second Model And Table Columns

```
public class UserDetailsDictionary
{
  public int DictId{get;set;}
  public string InterestName{get;set;}
  public string DetailsType{get;set;}
 }
```

3.] Third Table to store data

```
public class UserData
{
  public int UserId{get;set;}
  public int DictonaryId{get;set;}
  public bool _value {get;set;}
 }
```

I assume data is stored in database as you showing in your question

> (1,1,0)
>
> (1,1,1)(first user like basketball)
>
> (1,2,0)(first user does not have brown eyes)
>
> (2,1,1) (second user likes football)

Now Lets take one of your example

> (2,1,1) (second user likes football)

User With ID 2 have

> Blockquote

interest in Football (interest with id 1)

Now from api you can return an anonymous type

```
var m =(from data in _dbContext.UserData
Join details in _dbContext.UserDetails on data.UserID equals details.UserID
Join dict in _dbContext.UserDetailsDictionary on data.DictionaryID equals dict.DictID 
//where Condition if required 
select new {
UserName=details.UserName,
Interest= dict.IntersetName,
//_value=true/false 
}
).ToList();
```

Instead of Annonymous Type you can also return storngly Type Model as Json

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i know this solution (it is the simplest) 
but in my code i would like to dont use Joins like here. I want to get to UserDetailsDictionary from _dbContext.UsersDetails. 
or maybe im just in bad mood and what i wrote does not make sense ;)

Comment: For that you need flat tables instead of normalize tables Where in place of ID you store Actual Value . Than you can directly query from _dbContext without using Joins . But I will suggest you to use Normalize Tables . It will save you from lot of headache